# I want to reorder the way my data is displayed in my bar chart but can't figure it out

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm a beginner using rstudio and I've tried googling solutions but none have worked so far. What I want to do is have my data displayed on the bar chart in the order 0%, 50%, 100%, pilchard. I rearranged my data to follow this

| Bait_Type | Treatment | avg_per_ch_1d | std_err_24hr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0% Bio | Dry | -0.3027088 | 0.10449982 |
| 0% Bio | Filterd Sea Water | 0.1959978 | 0.24336969 |
| 0% Bio | Unfiltered Sea Water | -0.1845794 | 0.20669818 |
| 50% Bio | Dry | -0.0871318 | 0.06661162 |
| 50% Bio | Filterd Sea Water | 0.3479994 | 0.25427615 |
| 50% Bio | Unfiltered Sea Water | -0.3501732 | 0.32794720 |
| 100% Bio | Dry | -36.1509179 | 0.71514146 |
| 100% Bio | Filterd Sea Water | 11.7590984 | 1.11141054 |
| 100% Bio | Unfiltered Sea Water | 10.3144201 | 1.39823081 |
| Pilchard | Dry | -45.0024368 | 2.48731687 |
| Pilchard | Filterd Sea Water | 8.9346894 | 1.62343892 |
| Pilchard | Unfiltered Sea Water | 5.5411924 | 1.19679275 |

and hoped that would fix it but the bar chart is still outputing the data out of order

[image: ggplot output].
This is the code I used to arrange my data the desired way: `AVG_CH_24Hr <- avg_ch_24hr %>% arrange(factor(Bait_Type, levels=c('0% Bio', '50% Bio', '100% Bio', 'Pilchard')))`

This is the code i've been using to create my bar graph.

```
Lure_1day <- ggplot(AVG_CH_24Hr, aes(fill=Bait_Type, y=avg_per_ch_1d, x=Treatment))+
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity')+
  ggtitle('Average Percent Change 24hrs')+
  ylab('Average % Change')+
  theme_bw()
```

I've also tried adding the mutate argument to change the order

```
avg_ch_24hr %>%
  arrange(Bait_Type) %>%
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels=c('0% Bio', '50% Bio', '100% Bio', 'Pilchard'))) %>%
  ggplot(avg_ch_24hr, aes(fill=Bait_Type, y=avg_per_ch_1d, x=Treatment))+
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity')+
  ggtitle('Average Percent Change 24hrs')+
  ylab('Average % Change')+
  theme_bw()
```

but came up with this error.

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `name = factor(name, levels = c("0% Bio", "50% Bio", "100% Bio", "Pilchard"))`.
Caused by error:
! object 'name' not found
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: FYI, `arrange` is going to do nothing for ggplot images, your approach with `factor` is the right approach. `factor(name,...)` fails because there is no `name` in your data. Try `factor(Bait_Type, ...)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The use of `factor` is the right approach.
2. While doing no harm, `arrange` is doing nothing as far as ggplot is concerned.
3. You don't have a `name` in your data, you have `Bait_Type`, change to that.
4. When `ggplot(.)` is in a `%>%`-pipe, don't include the data frame object *again* in the call; in this case, it should be just `%>% ggplot(aes(...)) + ...`.

```r
avg_ch_24hr %>%
  mutate(Bait_Type = factor(Bait_Type, levels=c('0% Bio', '50% Bio', '100% Bio', 'Pilchard'))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill=Bait_Type, y=avg_per_ch_1d, x=Treatment))+
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity')+
  ggtitle('Average Percent Change 24hrs')+
  ylab('Average % Change')+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: The code worked with the mutate argument but its still placing 100% before 50%. Do you have any other suggestions.

Comment: I took your sample data and ran this code and got the now-attached image. There was a typo in my answer that likely contributed, please try again.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your code works now and the values are in the order I wanted.

Answer (score -1):

After some more googling I found that putting this before my ggplot code block fixed my problem.

`AVG_CH_24Hr$Bait_Type = factor(AVG_CH_24Hr$Bait_Type, levels = c("0% Bio", "50% Bio", "100% Bio", "Pilchard"))`

Comment: So you're saying that after my comment (saying that `factor` was right and `name` was not `Bait_Type`) and my answer (albeit with one typo), some time later you googled and found something that suggested you needed to run `factor` on `Bait_Type`?